# Error opening visual studio code

Tags: windows, windows-10, visual-studio-code

I try to open Visual Studio Code app and I get the following error: `"The stub received bad data."`
If I open the app again, it will open without a problem. This occurs with other apps.
I have Windows 10 Pro. Any idea or reason for this error?

[image]

I executed the commands (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/the-stub-received-bad-data/f4829753-484e-4cf8-b123-6caf2422d17b) and got the following answers:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow

> Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth

> [==========================100.0%==========================] No
>   component store corruption detected. The operation completed
>   successfully.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

> [==========================100.0%==========================] The
>   restore operation completed successfully. The operation completed
>   successfully.

But the problem continues

Comment: Yes, I have an idea: maybe the stub received bad data?

Comment: Google it :)  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/the-stub-received-bad-data/f4829753-484e-4cf8-b123-6caf2422d17b

Comment: @narzan I did but did not work any of the commands that showed there.

Comment: What other programs are having the same error?

Comment: @music2myear "Visual Studio 2015", "Services", "Event Viewer", "SourceTree"

Comment: Did you try to reinstall it?

Comment: @Dave The problem is not only with visual studio code, for example, how I reinstall "Event Viewer", formatting the PC? ;)